# Python Typeerror: All intermediate steps should be transformers and implement fit and transform

Tags: python, typeerror

I am working through the book "Hands-On Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn and TensorFlow" by Aurélien Géron. When I run the following code (copied from the book) I get an error message. How to resolve it?

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin 
rooms_ix, bedrooms_ix, population_ix, households_ix = 3, 4, 5, 6 

class CombinedAttributesAdder(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin): 
    def __init__( self, add_bedrooms_per_room = True): # no *args or ** kargs 
        self.add_bedrooms_per_room = add_bedrooms_per_room 
        def fit(self, X, y = None): 
            return self # nothing else to do 
        def transform(self, X):
            rooms_per_household = X[:, rooms_ix] / X[:, households_ix] 
            population_per_household = X[:, population_ix] / X[:, households_ix] 
            if self.add_bedrooms_per_room: 
                bedrooms_per_room = X[:, bedrooms_ix] / X[:, rooms_ix] 
                return np.c_[X, rooms_per_household, population_per_household, bedrooms_per_room] 
            else: 
                return np.c_[X, rooms_per_household, population_per_household] 
            attr_adder = CombinedAttributesAdder(add_bedrooms_per_room = False) 
            housing_extra_attribs = attr_adder.transform(housing.values)

from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline 
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler 
num_pipeline = Pipeline([('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy ="median")), ('attribs_adder', CombinedAttributesAdder()), ('std_scaler', StandardScaler()),])
housing_num_tr = num_pipeline.fit_transform(housing_num)
```

The error message:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-235-5722db8509c0> in <module>
     20 from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
     21 from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
---> 22 num_pipeline = Pipeline([('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy ="median")), ('attribs_adder', CombinedAttributesAdder()), ('std_scaler', StandardScaler()),])
     23 housing_num_tr = num_pipeline.fit_transform(housing_num)

~\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     70                           FutureWarning)
     71         kwargs.update({k: arg for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args)})
---> 72         return f(**kwargs)
     73     return inner_f
     74 

~\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py in __init__(self, steps, memory, verbose)
    112         self.memory = memory
    113         self.verbose = verbose
--> 114         self._validate_steps()
    115 
    116     def get_params(self, deep=True):

~\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py in
_validate_steps(self)
    157             if (not (hasattr(t, "fit") or hasattr(t, "fit_transform")) or not
    158                     hasattr(t, "transform")):
--> 159                 raise TypeError("All intermediate steps should be "
    160                                 "transformers and implement fit and transform "
    161                                 "or be the string 'passthrough' "

TypeError: All intermediate steps should be transformers and implement fit and transform or be the string 'passthrough' 'CombinedAttributesAdder()' (type <class '__main__.CombinedAttributesAdder'>) doesn't
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me the problem could be in the wrong indentation you have (unless it is just a mistyping). Methods `fit()` and `transform()` are not correctly indented (and so are `attr_adder` and `housing_extra_attribs` assignments). This way the instance of the class `CombinedAttributesAdder` that you are using in the pipeline is not a transformer, which is causing the error.

Comment: urggh, how could I overlook that.. many thanks Alessandro!